# how to rank the column values of each group

Tags: kdb

I have a table

[image]

1. Want to set the ranks based on max volume for each group .i.e date.
2. If volume is null, then dont rank it. Keep rank column empty for null volume.  (example see line 11 and 12 in expected output snapshot)
3. The rank=1 is our front contract, if sym flipped then it cannot be rank1 again after flip. example see output snapshot line 9, 13 and 15

expected output is

[image]

To generate the sample table, use below code.

```
tab:([]date:`date$();sym:`symbol$();name:`symbol$();volume:`float$();roll_rank:`int$());
`tab insert (2010.01.01;`ESH22;`ES;100.1;0Ni);
`tab insert (2010.01.01;`ESH23;`ES;500.1;0Ni);
`tab insert (2010.01.02;`ESH22;`ES;100.1;0Ni);
`tab insert (2010.01.02;`ESH23;`ES;800.1;0Ni);
`tab insert (2010.01.02;`ESH24;`ES;600.1;0Ni);
`tab insert (2010.01.02;`ESH25;`ES;550.1;0Ni);
`tab insert (2010.01.02;`ESH26;`ES;200.1;0Ni);
`tab insert (2010.01.03;`ESH23;`ES;600.1;0Ni);
`tab insert (2010.01.03;`ESH24;`ES;700.1;0Ni);
`tab insert (2010.01.03;`ESH26;`ES;0n;0Ni);
`tab insert (2010.01.03;`ESH25;`ES;500.1;0Ni);
`tab insert (2010.01.03;`ESH26;`ES;0n;0Ni);
`tab insert (2010.01.04;`ESH23;`ES;50.1;0Ni);
`tab insert (2010.01.05;`ESH23;`ES;300.1;0Ni);
`tab insert (2010.01.05;`ESH24;`ES;800.1;0Ni);
`tab insert (2010.01.05;`ESH25;`ES;100.1;0Ni);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will put the table in descending order by date, with the rank number in a separate column:

```
q)ungroup select volume:desc volume,ranknumber:1+til count volume by date from tab
```

Code ouput with the provided table data:

```
   date    volume ranknumber
----------------------------
2010.01.01 500.1  1
2010.01.01 100.1  2
2010.01.02 800.1  1
2010.01.02 600.1  2
2010.01.02 550.1  3
2010.01.02 200.1  4
2010.01.02 100.1  5
2010.01.03 700.1  1
2010.01.03 600.1  2
2010.01.03 500.1  3
2010.01.03        4
2010.01.03        5
2010.01.04 50.1   1
2010.01.05 800.1  1
2010.01.05 300.1  2
2010.01.05 100.1  3
```

Haven't thought of an elegant way of not including the null values in the rank order yet.

Edit: You could use "update" on the sorted table to remove the ranked null values - something like this would work (where tab2 is the previous output):

```
q)update ranknumber:0N from tab2 where ranked=0N
    date       ranked ranknumber
----------------------------
2010.01.01 500.1  1
2010.01.01 100.1  2
2010.01.02 800.1  1
2010.01.02 600.1  2
2010.01.02 550.1  3
2010.01.02 200.1  4
2010.01.02 100.1  5
2010.01.03 700.1  1
2010.01.03 600.1  2
2010.01.03 500.1  3
2010.01.03
2010.01.03
2010.01.04 50.1   1
2010.01.05 800.1  1
2010.01.05 300.1  2
2010.01.05 100.1  3
```

Comment: cool, let me check.. Also any thing for point no 3?

Comment: You could use a vector conditional for the null part: ungroup select volume:desc volume,ranknumber:?[null volume;0Nj; 1+til count volume] by date from tab